# How to fill the edges with good topology? Am i doing this correctly?

Tags: shortcut, topology

I've been scratching my head at attempting to connect the stretched octagon to the rest of the object(with good topology). Is the edge cuts that i created in the third image considered good (or at least half way decent?).  My process was to delete the faces as a whole, then manually fill one side of the octagon to the rest of the object(F shortcut when 2 edges selected). Afterwards, I'd cleaning up the fill using the cut tool (K shortcut). This was very manual.  Is there a better methodology? Is just a central part of 3D designing very specific nooks and crannies?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: http://topologyguides.com

Comment: The answer to this partly depends on where you want to be hard/soft. Do you want  sub-d to make any curvature for you, or will the final result be as seen?

Comment: The resulting faces will stay flat, hence why I thought this wasn't a bad result.  Isn't that the general consensus?  Move all poles and triangles to flat areas whenever possible? The outside edges will be subdivided to add worn detail rather then hard curves.